# Inkscape: converting object with filter to plain object

Tags: vector-graphics, inkscape

In Inkscape 0.48, giving 2 objects: A and B, I want to apply on A a filter (e.g: `Filters > Distort > Torn edges`) and to subtract the resulting object from B (with `Path > Difference`).

The problem is that object A is not a normal object. When I look at the `Edit path by nodes` tool, I can see my original nodes. `Path > Difference` does not work, and `Path > Object to path` nor even `Path > Trace bitmap...` does not seem to convert the object with filter to a normal object.

Is it possible at all, and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

OK, So I found a way. Mind you it is not pretty:

1. Duplicate the A object, and move the duplicate to an empty location.
2. Select the isolated duplicate and export the selection as a bitmap.
3. Import the exported bitmap and apply `Path > Trace bitmap...` with 2 colors.
4. Re-adjust the size and location over the original object A.
5. Delete A.
6. Now `Path > Difference` will work.